# jQuery onkeyup event: scan not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

Displays:

> Uncatched Reference error: scan not defined.

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
            function scan() {
                $("#result").text("<font style='color: green;'>Cote</font>");   console.log("Function ran");
    }

});

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <font style="font-size: 84px;">Scan card, please</font>
        <p id="result">cotes</p>
            <input style="font-size: 36px;" id="input" maxlength=16 autofocus onkeyup="scan();">
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: don't put util functions in a ready, they need to be global to be seen by inline js. since they don't do anything on their own, there's no need to defer.

Comment: What is your `scan` function scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your scan function is only accessible in the scope of:

```
function() {

   function scan() { ... }

}
```

You should place it outside this function at the level of the document:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
     function scan() { ... }
</script>
```

You should use $(document).ready for initializing the document once its content has been loaded. Over here, you are just declaring the scan function within the scope of this initialization function I've just mentioned but it is not within the scope of the event handler set at the onkeyup event. Therefore, function scan is not found.

If you have any further questions, let me know. If this solves the issue, don't forget to vote up! :)

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate your help. Your solution was correct. :)

Answer (score 1):

`scan` method definition should be outside of the other function's scope. See how you should modify your code:

```
function scan() {
    $("#result").text("<font style='color: green;'>Cote</font>");
    console.log("Function ran");
}

$(document).ready(function() { 
    // remove if not necessary
});
```

Comment: BTW, do you speak Russian?

Comment: @VladimirChampion yup